# Titanium, PHP and json encode

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to use a json string to fill up my titanium app. But normally I do not have information in front of the json string as the example below:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "total": 5,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "guid": "1d4aa3b2-c059-4fa7-a751-9bca735e4ebb",
            "picture": "http://skounis.s3.amazonaws.com/mobile-apps/barebone/photo-1.jpg",
            "title": "Wisi consequat sit zzril.",
            "body": "Ut vulputate te dolor ipsum nonummy, dolore enim accumsan veniam duis, nibh veniam at nulla. Adipiscing, dolore dolor lobortis et qui, consequat ea tation iusto qui, tation velit minim. Delenit elit, feugait nibh illum diam vulputate, feugiat erat et velit veniam, tation ea. Consequat magna et, iriure delenit zzril vel ea, eum amet ut autem consequat, tincidunt. Aliquam adipiscing vero dolore, magna ut vel et veniam, iriure odio ullamcorper erat vulputate, facilisi dolore hendrerit in accumsan, accumsan illum iriure quis nibh, nisl vulputate nostrud enim. Commodo, lorem luptatum erat ut elit, blandit dolor eu adipiscing ipsum, dolor.",
            "tags": ["feugait", "vel", "nulla"]
        }
    ]
}
```

So my question is how do I write an array that gives the sames output as this but where I can edit the information that comes first like total, id, and jsonrpc.

Thank you.

Comment: " But normally I do not have information in front of the json string..." "but where I can edit the information that comes first like..." huh what?

Comment: Take a look at [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

Answer (score 0):

You can sipmly use the php function json_decode to convert your JSON to a PHP array.

Here's the manual page : http://php.net/json_decode

Example of use :

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

    var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Output :

```
array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

---

To generate a JSON string, use json_encode.

Example for your case :

```
$array = Array("id"=>1, 
"jsonrpc"=>"2.0", 
"total"=>5, 
"result"=>Array(0=>Array
(
        "id"=>1,
        "guid"=> "1d4aa3b2-c059-4fa7-a751-9bca735e4ebb",
        "picture"=> "http://skounis.s3.amazonaws.com/mobile-apps/barebone/photo-1.jpg",
        "title"=> "Wisi consequat sit zzril.",
        "body"=> "Ut vulputate te dolor ipsum nonummy, dolore enim accumsan veniam duis, nibh veniam at nulla. Adipiscing, dolore dolor lobortis et qui, consequat ea tation iusto qui, tation velit minim. Delenit elit, feugait nibh illum diam vulputate, feugiat erat et velit veniam, tation ea. Consequat magna et, iriure delenit zzril vel ea, eum amet ut autem consequat, tincidunt. Aliquam adipiscing vero dolore, magna ut vel et veniam, iriure odio ullamcorper erat vulputate, facilisi dolore hendrerit in accumsan, accumsan illum iriure quis nibh, nisl vulputate nostrud enim. Commodo, lorem luptatum erat ut elit, blandit dolor eu adipiscing ipsum, dolor.",
        "tags"=>Array(0=>"feugait", 1=> "vel",2=> "nulla")
))
);

var_dump(json_encode($array));
```

Comment: I'm need to output the same code as I posted above but I cannot succeed because I encode everything and then the documents starts otherwise and nothing loads on the app.

Comment: @user2103237 Ok, you can write your array with the structure you want, and then use json_encode to convert it to JSON format.

Comment: @user2103237 I edited my answer with an array that'll give you the exact JSON string you wanted.